# Scroll to specific div on click with margin or padding

Tags: jquery, html

I have this Jquery code to scroll

```js
      $(".index-down-scroll").click(function() {
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(".home-page-catalog").offset().top},
              'slow');
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 999; width: 100%; height: 96px; background-color: red;"></div>
<div style="background-color: green; height: 800px;">
<div class="index-down-scroll" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 120px; font-size: 40px;">Down</div>
    <div style="margin-top: 300px;" class="w-clearfix home-page-catalog">
        Some text
    </div></div>
```

And i find a problem. I have fixed menu with height: 96px;
and if i use Jquery code, he scroll me to Div not taking into account the fact that there is a fixed menu. And because of this the Div is closing by my menu.
Can this be somehow corrected? Add for example the function margin or padding?

Comment: where is your html code ? can you please provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Made an example. Imagine that the menu overlaps the Div with the inscription: Some Text, and I want to take into account that there is a menu and it did not close Some Text.

Comment: @Usman Rana, edit first post.

Comment: i think you should clarify your problem with proper example and your efforts on it. I can't see any element causing to close another element here. Or may be you want something else.

Comment: Okay. what do you expect ?